# ASP.NET redirect all requests to single page and rewrite url so page appears to be in root

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting

I have a site where the customer only wants a single page in a sub-directory to be available. Any requests to other pages should be redirected to said page. The customer would also like the url to always appear to be the root domain.

So...

http://example.com/2019/2019.html -> http://example.com

I have the redirect working but the rewrite is not. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="2019/2019.html" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite to web root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rewrite" action uses the specified url to generate response which will be sent to the browser as a result, so, when you are using "Rewrite" the browser will not know the response is based on another address and therefor the address visible to the user will be still "/2019/2019.html".

"Redirect" actually returns a redirect response to the browser, so another request by the browser will be sent using new url (in your case "/") to the server. The "Redirect" solution is the proper way for your case.